# How to integrate a series using scipy.integrate.trapz()

Tags: pandas, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to get area-under-curve of an experimental data set that is currently type: series. The series is 2700 entries long, but I only want to integrate over the first 300 entries. The expected result is -0.2923 but the actual result using scipy.integrate.trapz() is 0.

```
import scipy
import pandas as pd

#display only first 10 entries to give a feel for the data:
dataseries.head(10) 
649.6   -0.000990
649.9   -0.000849
650.1   -0.000855
650.3   -0.001658
650.6   -0.001648
650.8   -0.001244
651.1   -0.001144
651.3   -0.001004
651.5   -0.000684
651.8   -0.001233


print(scipy.integrate.trapz(dataseries[:300], axis=0))
0.0
```

I (inelegantly) converted the series to an array, and the array to a list, then the integral works as expected on the list:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':dataseries.index, 'y':dataseries.values})
dataArray=df.values
datalist=[[0 for u in range(0, 300)] for y in range(0, 2)]
for c in range(0, 300):
    datalist[0][c]=dataArray[c][0]
    if math.isnan(dataArray[c][1]):
        datalist[1][c]=dataArray[c+1][1]
    else: 
       datalist[1][c]=dataArray[c][1]

print(scipy.integrate.trapz(datalist[1], datalist[0]))
-0.2923
```

Is there a way to integrate the first series directly?
If not, what is the cleanest, simplest way to get to the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one column, `y` , you can simply use df['y'][:300] to get the first 300 entries and directly pass to `trapz` function. Following is the minimal code that works , integrating first 5 entries of a dataframe.

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,3,7,8,10,15]), columns=['y'])
trapz(df['y'][:5])
```

output:

```
23.5
```